# How can I create multiple autofilter using xlsxwriter python package

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

when I write

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook( 'text.xlsx' )
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.autofilter( A1:A10 )
worksheet.autofilter( B1:B10 ) <- only these apply
```

the second autofilter cancel the first one

Comment: why not do `worksheet.autofilter('A1:B10')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I create multiple autofilter using xlsxwriter

It isn't possible to create more than one autofilter per worksheet in Excel. Therefore it isn't possible to do it with XlsxWriter. Only the last autofilter written is applied.

In this particular case the filter ranges are next to each other so they could be combined to make one range, like this:

```py
worksheet.autofilter('A1:B10')
```